# Postgres cursor based pagination performance

Tags: postgresql

I have created a dummy `panda` table with 1.000.000 rows of random data. Table has `id` primary key column of `uuid` type.

Using [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) I do a cursor based pagination forward and backward for the same `id` cursor. Forward generated query takes 900ms (~1s), backward takes 0.06ms (~0.006s)

Why first is slower and is there a way to improve it? Strange thing is that if I replace `"order_cmp"."Panda_id_0"` with actual value (second example) performance will be good again 0.06ms (~0.006s).

Forward:

```
explain analyze
select * from
    "public"."panda",
    (
    select
        "public"."panda"."id" as "Panda_id_0"
    from
        "public"."panda"
    where
        ("public"."panda"."id") = ('ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348')) as "order_cmp"
where
    "public"."panda"."id" >= "order_cmp"."Panda_id_0"
order by
    "public"."panda"."id" asc
limit 4 offset 1;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.98..1.52 rows=4 width=86) (actual time=919.298..919.303 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..44539.57 rows=333333 width=86) (actual time=919.295..919.301 rows=5 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (panda.id >= panda_1.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 999990
        ->  Index Scan using panda_pkey on panda  (cost=0.42..29536.92 rows=1000000 width=70) (actual time=0.017..607.298 rows=999995 loops=1)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..2.65 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=999995)
              ->  Index Only Scan using panda_pkey on panda panda_1  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = 'ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348'::uuid)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.166 ms
Execution Time: 919.332 ms
```

Previous forward query with replaced `"order_cmp"."Panda_id_0"` to actual value

```
explain analyze
select * from
    "public"."panda",
    (
    select
        "public"."panda"."id" as "Panda_id_0"
    from
        "public"."panda"
    where
        ("public"."panda"."id") = ('ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348')) as "order_cmp"
where
    "public"."panda"."id" >= 'ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348'
order by
    "public"."panda"."id" asc
limit 4 offset 1;
```

```
Limit  (cost=1.73..5.26 rows=4 width=86) (actual time=0.032..0.040 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..4412.29 rows=5001 width=86) (actual time=0.013..0.038 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using panda_pkey on panda  (cost=0.42..4347.13 rows=5001 width=70) (actual time=0.007..0.028 rows=5 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id >= 'ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348'::uuid)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..2.65 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=5)
              ->  Index Only Scan using panda_pkey on panda panda_1  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = 'ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348'::uuid)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.224 ms
Execution Time: 0.073 ms
```

---

Unrelated, just to compare:

Backward:

```
explain analyze 
select * from
    "public"."panda",
    (
    select
        "public"."panda"."id" as "Panda_id_0"
    from
        "public"."panda"
    where
        ("public"."panda"."id") = ('ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348')) as "order_cmp"
where
    "public"."panda"."id" <= "order_cmp"."Panda_id_0"
order by
    "public"."panda"."id" desc
limit 4 offset 1;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.97..1.51 rows=4 width=85) (actual time=0.025..0.030 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.83..4503.05 rows=33280 width=85) (actual time=0.023..0.029 rows=5 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (panda.id <= panda_1.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2
        ->  Index Scan Backward using panda_pkey on panda  (cost=0.42..3002.81 rows=99840 width=69) (actual time=0.011..0.017 rows=7 loops=1)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=7)
              ->  Index Only Scan using panda_pkey on panda panda_1  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = 'ffff581b-ef0c-4cb8-9ece-25504e420348'::uuid)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.099 ms
Execution Time: 0.046 ms
```

Offset based:

```
explain analyze
select * from
    "public"."panda"
order by
    "public"."panda"."id" asc
limit 4 offset 500000;

Limit  (cost=14768.67..14768.79 rows=4 width=70) (actual time=316.159..316.161 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using panda_pkey on panda  (cost=0.42..29536.92 rows=1000000 width=70) (actual time=0.012..298.960 rows=500004 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.051 ms
Execution Time: 316.179 ms
```

Comment: What is the point of the more convoluted query when the simple one gets the job done and is much quicker?

Comment: The backward query would also be slow if the value given were not so close to that end of the range of all values.

Comment: @jjanes it's generated by prisma, I have no control over it and want to understand why postgres is slow for some reason?